# Decrement TIME type values by one minute in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table with a column of type TIME. I need to decrement all the time values by one minute. For ex, 9:25:00 should be updated as 9:24:00 and 2:00:00 should become 1:59:00. How can this be achieved?

Comment: How have you tried to approach the problem so far? Please supply code inside your question.

Comment: Please read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes, but I was expecting some kind of  DateTime related function to be available for this. I was not aware of 'interwal'. Also, what kind of code for this are you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update your_table
set time_column = time_column - interval 1 minute
```